# Delphi 10.1 Android How to get Firebase Device Token

Tags: android, delphi

I have tried:

```
APushService := TPushServiceManager.Instance.GetServiceByName(TPushService.TServiceNames.GCM);
APushService.AppProps[TPushService.TAppPropNames.GCMAppID] := '"mobilesdk_app_id" '; // my "mobilesdk_app_id" from google-services.json
AServiceConnection := TPushServiceConnection.Create(APushService);
AServiceConnection.Active := True;
AServiceConnection.OnChange := OnServiceConnectionChange;
AServiceConnection.OnReceiveNotification := OnReceiveNotificationEvent;

ADeviceID := APushService.DeviceIDValue[TPushService.TDeviceIDNames.DeviceID];
AdeviceToken := APushService.DeviceTokenValue[TPushService.TDeviceTokenNames.DeviceToken];
```

`ADeviceID` comes up correctly, by `AdeviceToken` comes up blank.

Answer (score 2):

it's because:

```
APushService.AppProps[TPushService.TAppPropNames.GCMAppID] := '"mobilesdk_app_id"
```

is wrong and this property does not relate to the **mobilesdk_app_id**. It's related to the **SENDER ID**. This value can be found under *settings -> cloud messaging -> sender Id*. Once you put this value, you will receive the token.