# How to make a connection between a service and Delphi under Android?

Tags: android, delphi

I add this in the android manifest to create a service :

```
<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

and i have this code in java :

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

    }
    // [END refresh_token]

}
```

now the question, how i can make the connection between MyFirebaseInstanceIDService and Delphi ? how from MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.onTokenRefresh i can fire a method declared in delphi ? Or how from delphi i can get the instance of MyFirebaseInstanceIDService

do we need to use indent for this ?

Comment: Im a bit confused by your question. You want a solution in Delphi, right? The java code is included just for demonstration purpose?

Comment: Possibly your question duplicates [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40888708/4236400). Further there is [this tutorial for FCM with Delphi](http://thundaxsoftware.blogspot.de/2017/01/firebase-cloud-messaging-with-delphi.html). There is a [delphi code library for Firebase on github](https://github.com/spinettaro/Firebase4Delphi), too. It is said, that it is in alpha. It is described in [this blog post](http://www.danielespinetti.it/2016/06/simple-chat-messaging-system-with.html).

Comment: @RenéHoffmann yes i want a delphi solution, want to know how the service can push to my delphi app the refreshedToken or how my delphi app can ask the service for the refreshedToken