# FirebaseOptions.fromResource return null making all firebase framework not working

Tags: delphi, firebase, google-play-services, firebase-cloud-messaging

i have in my project FirebaseOptions.fromResource who return null

```
public static FirebaseOptions fromResource(Context context) {
    zzam com_google_android_gms_common_internal_zzam = new zzam(context);
    Object string = com_google_android_gms_common_internal_zzam.getString("google_app_id");
    return TextUtils.isEmpty(string) ? null : new FirebaseOptions(string, com_google_android_gms_common_internal_zzam.getString("google_api_key"), com_google_android_gms_common_internal_zzam.getString("firebase_database_url"), com_google_android_gms_common_internal_zzam.getString("ga_trackingId"), com_google_android_gms_common_internal_zzam.getString("gcm_defaultSenderId"), com_google_android_gms_common_internal_zzam.getString("google_storage_bucket"));
}
```

the function is obfuscated but it's seam that `com_google_android_gms_common_internal_zzam.getString("google_app_id");` return an empty string.

I have put the google-services.json at the root dir (ie the folder ./ where is the AndroidManifest.xml)

This is all the folders I have :

```
\assets
\bin (contain kiskis.apk)
\classes (contain classes.dex)
\debug (contain libmyapp.so)
\library
  \lib
    \armeabi
    \armeabi-v7a (contain libmyapp.so)
    \mips
\res
```

Where must I put the google-services.json? But even in the google-services.json, I don't see anywhere any key with the name "google_app_id", so where this key come from?

NOTE: i read about this:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/gradle/

> The google-services plugin has two main functions:
>
> Process the google-services.json file and produce Android resources
>   that can be used in your application's code. See Adding the JSON File
>   more information

But i don't understand how this work? because i m not under android studio (i m under Delphi), so i don't understand what is a gradle and what it's do exactly... does this The Google Services Gradle Plugin process the google-services.json at run time or at compile time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle is build system Android Studio uses to compile and build final .apk package from source code and resources.

Google Services Gradle Plugin is compile time plugin for Gradle that takes `google-services.json` file and generates appropriate xml string resources file that will subsequently be compiled into binary resource used by your application.

So adding `google-services.json` as-is to Delphi project is useless because Firebase does not use that file directly in any way.

Since both `google-services.json` and generated `values.xml` file are simple humanly readable files and you only need to create `values.xml` file once in a while, you can manually convert one to the other, filling appropriate xml fields.

You can find its structure described at link you referenced [The Google Services Gradle Plugin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/gradle/)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="default_web_client_id" translatable="false">1035469437078-e8mr503bun5eaevqctn4u807q4hpi44s.apps.googleusercontent.com</string>
    <string name="gcm_defaultSenderId" translatable="false">1035469437078</string>
    <string name="firebase_database_url" translatable="false">https://myapp.firebaseio.com</string>
    <string name="google_app_id" translatable="false">1:1035469437078:android:73a4fb8297b2cd4f</string>
    <string name="google_api_key" translatable="false">AIzaSyFE3G2eN0XZPl-IeEvZhzKOAgC9vy9imVE</string>
    <string name="google_storage_bucket" translatable="false">myapp.appspot.com</string>
</resources>
```

After you have done that part you will have to compile `values.xml` and include it in Delphi project.

How to do that you can find at [Embed Facebook SDK for Android in your Delphi mobile app](https://blog.grijjy.com/2017/01/30/embed-facebook-sdk-for-android-in-your-delphi-mobile-app-part-2/) Principle of creating `R.java` and including `R$` classes in the `Classes.dex` is the same.

Comment: thanks ... done it's work now :) now i need just to understand this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43522010/how-to-make-a-connection-between-a-service-and-delphi-under-android and i have finish with firebase :)